# Share the same shadow DOM between several shadow hosts?

Tags: html, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm just discovering Web Components and I'm not sure yet to have it understood well.

But here's my question.  Seems it has a lot of advantages.
I would like to know if it is possible to share the same shadow DOM on several shadow hosts ?

What I want is several instances of an element on my webpage.
If the (single) shadow DOM is updated, all the instances would be updated too automatically.

Is it one of the uses of the shadow DOM stuff; and how can I achieve it ?

Thanks !

Comment: No. Every shadow host owns its own shadow DOM. You'll needvto duplicate DOM content

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same effect by having a containing component that listens for an event when a property changes and passes the value down to child components. This way you don't share the shadow DOM instance itself, but you re-use the component without any code duplication.

```js
class XContainer extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.total = 0;
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {    
    this.addEventListener('x-increment', this.onIncrement);
    
    this.onIncrement = this.onIncrement.bind(this);
  }
  
  onIncrement(event) {
    this.total = this.total + event.detail.amount;
    
    this.querySelectorAll('x-counter').forEach((counterEl) => {
      counterEl.total = this.total;
    });
  }
}
customElements.define('x-container', XContainer);


class XControls extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <button>+</button>
    `;
  }
    
  connectedCallback() {    
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', this.onClick);
    
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  onClick(event) {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('x-increment', {
      bubbles: true,
      composed: true,
      detail: {
        amount: 1,
      }
    }));
  }
}
customElements.define('x-controls', XControls);


class XCounter extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <h2>Total: <span>0</span>
    `;
  }
  
  set total(value) {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('span').innerText = value;
  }
}
customElements.define('x-counter', XCounter);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Web Component 101</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>  
  <body>

    <x-container>
      <x-counter></x-counter>
      <hr>
      <x-counter></x-counter>
      <hr>
      <x-controls></x-controls>
    </x-container>
    
  </body>
</html>
```